# Simple Arithmetic in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a program that gives a list and back a newer list that have even numbers in the first list, as below:

```
evennom([1,3,2,4,3,2,1,2],out)
out = [2,4,2,2]
```

My Code is as below:

```
evennom([],[]).  
evennom(H1|T1],[H2|T2):- H2 is H1 mod 2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close - there needs to be something that removes the first element when the `mod 2` operation fails. Also, your "copy" rule was not entirely correct.

Try this:

```
evennom([], []).
evennom([H|T1], [H|T2]) :- H rem 2 =:= 0, !, evennom(T1, T2).
evennom([_|T1], T2) :- evennom(T1, T2).
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but backs an error that "Type error goal: mod 2 is 0"

Comment: @Mahdi This should do the trick. After 15+ years of *not* doing Prolog, I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: Syntax Error : evennom([H|T1], [H|T2]) :- H rem<HERE> 2 =:= 0, !, evennom(T1, T2).

Comment: I find it you should just using "mod" instead of "rem"

Answer (score 0):

Prolog does the recursion for you..

```
evennom(ListIn, ListOut) :-
    findall(Even, (nth0(_, ListIn, Even), 0 is (Even mod 2)), ListOut).
```